# C# Displaying Two Lists in Console Window

Tags: c#

I'm working on a algorithm that will have an array of populations which will then each have a list of 60 weights that are randomly generated numbers. This goes through the neural network and produces a result for each population member which is being stored in a list called results. I've done all that and I now want to display both the list of results and the array of lists called populationWeights in the console window so that there will be numbers going down from 1 to 60 and the next to that will be the corresponding result from the list called results. What is the easiest way to do this in c# based on the code i have currently?

Quick note populationWeights is an array of lists so there is 60 lists in an array (the population) and then those lists contain 60 random numbers (the weights).

```
        var populationSize = 60;
        var weights = 60;

        List<double>[] populationWeights = new List<double>[populationSize];
        List<double> results = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
        {
            populationWeights[i] = new List<double>();
            for(int j = 0; j < weights; j++)
            {
                populationWeights[i].Add(((_rand.NextDouble() * 2) - 1));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < populationWeights.Length; i++)
        {
            results.Add(GetResults(populationWeights[i]));
            Console.WriteLine(results[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I want the console window to look this this.

This far left hand side being the number of the index in the array for each list e.g list[0] in array of lists populationWeights. And then the right hand side being the results.

```
0 0.00000343
1 0.00000034
2 0.34984387
3 0.34734934
4 0,03470943
```

...

Comment: So on the first line, you want results[0], followed by populationWeights[0][0], populationWeights[0][1], etc. etc. through populationWeights[0][59]? And then the next line results[1], populationWeights[1][0], etc. Is that right?

Comment: Try following :             foreach (List<double> row in populationWeights)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.Select(x => x.ToString())));
            }

Comment: Yeah that's how i would want it Ed.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want your output to look like. Your explanation makes no sense to me.

Comment: Edited post so you can see what i'm looking for.

Comment: What's in the two collections when that output is produced? Is the comma a typo?

Comment: Comma is a typo. populationWeights is just an array of lists (60) and then each list has 60 random numbers. Results is just 60 numbers. Each results corresponds to the number of a list in the array. e.g result 0 is the results for population 0 which is the first list in populationWeights.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("0 0.00000343\n1 0.00000034\n2 0.34984387\n3 0.34734934\n4 0,03470943");`. Have a great day, sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string interpolation to format:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{i},{results[i]}");
```

[More on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

Comment: Thanks this works. Do you have anywhere i can read up on this as i haven't seen this before?